# Using Git, is it true that after making some changes, we can commit it to any branch?

Tags: git

Say, if a project using Git is all committed, with `master` and `foo` branch both point to the same commit.  If we are now on the `master` branch, and change some files, it seems that we can switch to the `foo` branch, or even create a new branch:

```
git checkout -b bar
```

and commit the changes to any of the 3 branches?  So it is like, the changes remain "flexible" for the programming to commit to whichever branch chosen?  (even commit to `foo` if there is one or several more commits already done in the `foo` branch, as long as the modified files didn't overlap with any files in those commits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You will be stopped from changing branches if there is a conflict. Otherwise, it Just Works.

Comment: it seems the "conflict" in this case is a "filename" conflict, instead of "line content" conflict?

Comment: doesn't the filename becomes a "superset" of line content?

Comment: I don't think it'll do it automatically for you. You can use `git stash` to help you merge across uncommitted content to another branch instead if you wish.

Comment: right, I mean it won't let you commit to a branch if that branch already has the file "readme" changed and committed and you changed the "readme" file as well.  And it doesn't matter if your change is line 1000 and the commit there is line 20 -- your commit still will not go through

Comment: Correct. Use `git stash` to carry the change across instead. When you `git stash pop`, it will merge it if possible.